# How get the id of a bootstrap html <a> tag id and pass it to django views.py?

Tags: python, jquery, django

I am using bootstrap tabs navigation bar and I want to retrieve the id of the  tag and pass it to my view but my main issue though is I am not using them in my urls.py. Here is my urls.py file.

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    index, add_task, update_task,
    delete_task, update_categories,
    delete_all_task
)


urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name="home"),
    path('add-task/', add_task, name="add-task"),
    path('update-task/<int:pk>/', update_task, name="update-task"),
    path('delete-task/<int:pk>/', delete_task, name="delete-task"),
    path('update-category/', update_categories, name="update-category"),
    path('delete_all_tasks/', delete_all_task, name="delete_all_tasks"),
]
```

And here is the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
from .models import Tasks, Category
from .forms import AddTaskForm, UpdateTaskForm, UpdateCategoryForm


def get_task_minid(categories):
    id_list = []
    for task in categories:
        id_list.append(task.id)
    min_id = min(id_list)
    return min_id


def index(request):
    tasks = Tasks.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    if len(categories) > 1:
        min_id = get_task_minid(categories)

    if request.method == "POST":
        category = request.POST.get('category')
        cat = Category.objects.create(name=category)
        cat.save()
        return redirect('home')

    context = {
        'tasks': tasks,
        'categories': categories,
        'min_id': min_id,
    }
    return render(request, 'Todo/index.html', context)
```

and here is the index.HTML

```
<div class="" id="Todo-tasks">


                            <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
            
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-5 col-sm-3">
                                        <div class="card-header">
                                            <span>All Categories</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="nav flex-column nav-tabs h-100" id="vert-tabs-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                                        {% for cat in categories  %}
                                        {% if cat.id == min_id %}
                                        <a class="nav-link active" id="vert-tabs-{{cat}}-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#vert-tabs-{{cat}}"
                                         role="tab" aria-controls="vert-tabs-{{cat}}" aria-selected="true">{{cat}}</a>
                                        {% else %}
                                        <a class="nav-link" id="vert-tabs-{{cat}}-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#vert-tabs-{{cat}}"
                                         role="tab" aria-controls="vert-tabs-{{cat}}" aria-selected="false">{{cat}}</a>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        <div class="card-footer mt-3">
                                            <form action="" method="POST"> 
                                                {% csrf_token %}
                                                <input type="text" name="category" placeholder="Add category" class="new-input cat" aria-label="Add new category" />
                                                <button type="submit" class="new">+</button>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="{% url 'update-category' %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-inverse-warning d-block mt-5">Manage Categories</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-7 col-sm-9">
                                        <div class="tab-content" id="vert-tabs-tabContent">
                                        {% for cat in categories %}
                                        {% if cat.id == min_id %}
                                        <div class="tab-pane text-left fade show active" id="vert-tabs-{{cat}}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="vert-tabs-{{ cat }}-tab">
                                            <ul class="list-unstyled border pb-4">
                                                <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between justify-content-center">
                                                    {{ cat }}
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <form action="" class="p-0 justify-content-end" method="post">    
                                                            <input type="text" name="search" class="form-input pl-3" placeholder="Search for tasks..."/>
                                                        </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                {% for task in cat.tasks.all %}
                                                <li class="align-content-center"><a>{{task.text}}
                                                    <small class="badge bg-success">{{task.due_date|timeuntil|upto:','}}</small>
                                                    <span class=""><a href="{% url 'update-task' task.id %}" ><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a></span>
                                                    <span class=""><a href="{% url 'delete-task' task.id %}" ><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a></span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                {% empty %}
                                                    <h3 class="alert alert-info m-5"><i class="fas fa-alert-outline"></i> Please add new tasks to categories</h3>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        {% else %}
                                            <div class="tab-pane text-left fade show" id="vert-tabs-{{cat}}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="vert-tabs-{{ cat }}-tab">
                                            <ul class="list-unstyled border pb-4">
```

Now, how I am thinking of a way to get the h ref in the  like(h ref="vert-tabs-{{cat}}" I want to get the value of the cat variable anytime I switch to a different sort of view or tab content.
Any help would be so appreciated even JavaScript or j query.
Thank you in advance...

Comment: Ok thanks a lot please give me a second.

Comment: Try passing the value in href and give it a name in **urls.py** and then you can take it as an argument in your view function.